# Add image dimensions automatically to <img>

Tags: php, jquery, image, frontend, dimensions

I scored my website on gtmetrix.com.

It recommends adding image dimensions to all my images. The thing is, I need some way of adding these automatically, so if the image changes, the dimentions are updated.

What I have

```
<img src="bla.png">
```

What I'd like to have

```
<img src="bla.png" width="{width of image}" height="{height of img}">
```

Is there a php way or a jquery way to do this?
For a wordpress site.

Comment: Using jQuery to calculate image dimensions on load will likely actually slow your site down compared to not having the dimensions there. My site calculates the dimensions of uploaded images and stores them to the database where PHP retrieves them on load but mine isn't a WP site. In fact doing anything on load is probably going to be detrimental to page load speeds.

Comment: database approach works great IMO.

Answer (score 1):

PHP:

```
<?php
list($width, $height) = getimagesize("bla.png");
echo "<img src='bla.png' width='$width' height='$height'>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `image onload` event to calculate the dimensions of image. Pure javascript approach, something like ;

```
var image = new Image();

image.onload = function()
{
  //after load complete you will get the image dimensions here from 
  //image.width and image.height
}

image.src = 'image url';
```

Comment: IMO it defies the whole point of specifying image dimensions in the markup

Comment: @Ejay OP can assign dimensions in markup on `image.onload` event

Comment: yes but it still will wait for the image(s) to load completely, so the page will _re-render_ anyway.

Comment: No full page will not going to re-render, only the specific image width and height attribute will update after image load completly

Comment: you're right about _re-rendering_ :) The particular term I was trying to use is _reflow and repaint_ https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rendering#SpecifyImageDimensions

Answer (score 0):

In php it's `getimagesize($file)` if you are outputting images dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it with PHP not with javascript. If you add it with jQuery / javascript, the width and height would be added after loading. The main reason of specifying width and height is to let the engine render the page faster. It would not be of any help if it as added after loading.

You can use the index 3 of the returned array from `getimagesize()` directly in the image tag.  It contains a string with height="yyy" width="xxx" an can be used directly in an IMG tag.

```
<?php
    list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize("file.png");
    echo "<img src='file.png' $attr />";
?>
```

You can visit http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php for more details on this function.